# Vb2010 - Snake Game Issue

Tags: vb.net

I currently making a "Snake" game in VB2010. I am using picture boxes to create the snake. The snake moves fine and it picks up the apples fine.

But when I turn the snake Left or Up it only displays the first 5 segments of the snake. When the snake travels Right or Down it displays the entire snake. I am completely stumped on what is happening.

Here is my code to Move the Snake.

```
 'Moving the Body Of the Snake
            For i As Integer = (Length - 1) To 1 Step (-1)
                Snake(i).X = Snake(i - 1).X
                Snake(i).Y = Snake(i - 1).Y
                SnakeBody(i).Location = New Point(Snake(i).X, Snake(i).Y)
                Snake(i).Facing = Snake(i - 1).Facing
            Next i

            'Moves the Head of the Snake
            'Moves Left
            If Snake(0).Facing = 1 Then
                Snake(0).X = Snake(0).X - 20
                SnakeBody(0).Location = New Point(Snake(0).X, Snake(0).Y)

                ' Moves Up
            ElseIf Snake(0).Facing = 2 Then
                Snake(0).Y = Snake(0).Y - 20
                SnakeBody(0).Location = New Point(Snake(0).X, Snake(0).Y)

                ' Moves Right
            ElseIf Snake(0).Facing = 3 Then
                Snake(0).X = Snake(0).X + 20
                SnakeBody(0).Location = New Point(Snake(0).X, Snake(0).Y)

                ' Moves Down
            ElseIf Snake(0).Facing = 4 Then
                Snake(0).Y = Snake(0).Y + 20
                SnakeBody(0).Location = New Point(Snake(0).X, Snake(0).Y)
            End If
              Length += 1
```

Also here is the code that Add's one segment to the snake when it comes in contact with the apple.

```
'Checks to see if the head of the snake finds the food


If Snake(0).X = Food.Left And Snake(0).Y = Food.Top Then
        LoadSnakeBody()

        'Placing the new body on its place
        If Snake(Length - 1).Facing = 1 Then        'Looking left
            Snake(Length).X = Snake(Length - 1).X - SnakeBody(0).Width
            Snake(Length).Y = Snake(Length - 1).Y
            SnakeBody(Length).Location = New Point(Snake(Length).X, Snake(Length).Y)
            SnakeBody(Length).Visible = True

        ElseIf Snake(Length - 1).Facing = 2 Then    'Looking up
            Snake(Length).X = Snake(Length - 1).X
            Snake(Length).Y = Snake(Length - 1).Y + SnakeBody(0).Height
            SnakeBody(Length).Location = New Point(Snake(Length).X, Snake(Length).Y)
            SnakeBody(Length).Visible = True

        ElseIf Snake(Length - 1).Facing = 3 Then    'Looking right
            Snake(Length).X = Snake(Length - 1).X - SnakeBody(0).Width
            Snake(Length).Y = Snake(Length - 1).Y
            SnakeBody(Length).Location = New Point(Snake(Length).X, Snake(Length).Y)
            SnakeBody(Length).Visible = True

        ElseIf Snake(Length - 1).Facing = 4 Then    'Looking down
            Snake(Length).X = Snake(Length - 1).X
            Snake(Length).Y = Snake(Length - 1).Y - SnakeBody(0).Height
            SnakeBody(Length).Location = New Point(Snake(Length).X, Snake(Length).Y)
            SnakeBody(Length).Visible = True
        End If

        PlaceFood()
    End If
```

If anyone could tell me what is wrong I would appreciate it sooo much!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hazarding a guess (more code might help; also, IANA VB expert) - is this some kind of boundary problem where `Snake(0).X` and `Snake(0).Y` can't go below 0 or something?

Other suggestion: check the signs of your left-facing body-segment addition code.  I think this might be a problem:

```
Snake(Length).X = Snake(Length - 1).X - SnakeBody(0).Width
```

If the segment is facing left, and we're trying to add a piece to the end, we need to move to the right, i.e. PLUS `SnakeBody(0).Width`.

```
Snake(Length).X = Snake(Length - 1).X + SnakeBody(0).Width
```

Hopefully this helps.  I did a snake game when I was in school, so I feel your pain with getting all the directions and body segment additions working out properly.